# Using Integration By Parts for $\int\sec^2(x)\tan(x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

Evaluate $\int\sec^2(x)\tan(x)\,\mathrm dx$

I know we can use $\text{substitution}$, but I instinctively used Integration By Parts and am not getting the right answer. What am I missing? [image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Posting  questions via images is frowned upon. Use mathjax.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: Note you have an integral of the form $ \int f(x)f'(x)dx $ 
look at the derivative of $f^2(x) $ and see the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\frac {\tan^2 \theta} 2 + C$ is not incorrect! Try differentiating it again, you'll get the same thing.

We have $1 + \tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta$ (divide the identity $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ by $\cos^2 \theta$ if you haven't seen this before) so we could write:

$$\frac {\tan^2 \theta} 2 + C = \frac {\sec^2 \theta} 2 + C - \frac 1 2$$

and writing a new arbitrary constant $C' = C - \frac 1 2$ gives you the cleaner:

$$\int \sec^2 \theta \tan \theta d\theta =\frac {\tan^2 \theta} 2 + C = \frac {\sec^2 \theta} 2 + C'$$

This is a quirk of "indefinite" integration, you are not just looking at one function, but a family of functions that all differ by a constant. You are free to shift this constant without really changing anything, because the constant will always just differentiate away to zero. Formally speaking we are saying that the set of functions $\{f_C(\theta) =\sec^2 \theta + C : C \in \mathbb R\}$ is equal to the set of functions $\{g_C(\theta) = \tan^2 \theta + C : C \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: You're not going to get any down votes from me. +1.

Comment: Neither from me and (+1)

Comment: I realise the edit seemed a bit confrontational, the first vote was a -1 which I assume was for answering what they deemed a "bad question".

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$$\text{Since } \int u\; du = u^2/2 +c_1, \text{we write }\int \sec x \;d( \sec x) = \frac{\sec^2 x }{2}+ c_1 $$

Note that

$$ \frac{\tan^2 x }{2}+ c_2  \;\text{is also correct due to trig identity} $$

$ \sec^2x -\tan^2 x=1. $

Answer (score 0):

Hint: U-Substitution is the most efficient way to approach this integral.

Another hint: What is the derivative of $tan(x)$?